# Why string assignment in javaScript is case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, css

I have create simple html page with one button that change its color when clicked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="if (this.style.backgroundColor == 'Red') {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'Green'
    }
    else {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red'
    }
     alert(this.style.backgroundColor)">
    ok
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

It is surprising for me that `alert(this.style.backgroundColor)` return *red* instead of *Red*. **Why?** There is an assignment `this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red'` and in this *Red* start with capital letter.

Comment: This isn't really anything to do with string assignment in JavaScript. The value is actually set to `'Red'` but this is then transformed to lowercase as per the CSS/DOM specifications.

Comment: Quick test: `var s = 'Red'; alert(s);`. Conclusion: String assignment in general is not case-insensitive.

Comment: @FelixKling That test is questionable as `window.alert(…)` is a host object's method known to convert its argument to string ;-) Consider `var s = 'Red'; s === 'red'` in a script console instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS styles aren't saved as literal strings, they're converted to an internal, canonical representation of the style. Color styles are case-insensitive, and the canonical representation is lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS properties are case insensitive.

Browsers are allowed to normalise them.

Answer (score 0):

According to W3C, the color unit (color names) are case-insensitive.

4.1. Basic color keywords

The list of basic color keywords is: aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, gray, green, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, silver, teal, white, and yellow. The color names are ***case-insensitive***.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#colorunits

Answer (score 0):

This is not just assigning a string to a variable, but assigning a string to an object's property.

Object's property could has custom setter/getter behaviors.

`this.style` is a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object which has the `backgroundColor` setter/getter implementation with native code.

An example is:

```
var o = {a: '',  get foo() {return this.a.toLowerCase();}, set foo(x) {this.a = x;}};
o.foo = 'Red';
console.log(o.foo); // will be 'red'
```